# Why React.FC doesn't allow me to just return children?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

While trying to create a component I realized a situation.

Only returning `children`

```
interface FooProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode
}

const Foo: React.FC<FooProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return children
}
```

Will give me an error saying:

```
 Type '({ children }: PropsWithChildren<FooProps>) => ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'FC<FooProps>'.  
  Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.  
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.
```

But if I return `children` inside any jsx, or even `Fragment`:

```
const Foo: React.FC<FooProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return <>{children}</>
}
```

It won't give me any error.

The obvious answer to this is that the types are incompatible, `ReactNode` is not assignable to type `ReactElement<any, any> | null`, as the error says, but my question is Why?

Why returning a `ReactNode` (e.g. `children`) isn't allowed? Shouldn't it be allowed?

Something extra to ask would be if this is something about `React.FC` and probably other type will be ok if I return `ReactNode` or if this is with all react components?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `React.ReactNode` type is a union type. Let's see what the type definition for it looks like,

```js
type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;
```

**Expected return type when you create a functional component with generic `FC`**

```
ReactElement<any, any> | null
```

So when you return the `children` directly from the component the compiler complains because the types are simply not compatible. The reason being `ReactElement` is a valid `React.ReactNode` but not the other way around, because `React.ReactNode` can also be a value of type `ReactFragment` or `ReactPortal` and so on.

It is obvious that it will create a type mismatch with `ReactElement`. But when you return the `children` inside a `Fragment` the compiler no longer complains because the return type becomes valid. Take a look at this example without the `FC` generic,

```
// The return type of Foo is inferred as React.ReactNode
// Compiler doesn't complain because we don't annotate the return type
const Foo = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren<FooProps>) => {
  return children;
};

// But when you use React.FC generic it is the same as annotating the return type
// of Foo as `React.ReactElement`

// compiler will complain because of the type mismatch
const Foo = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren<FooProps>): React.ReactElement => {
  return children;
};
```

**Example for why it works when you return the `children` inside a `Fragment`**

```js
// Without generic FC
// Return type infered as JSX.Element which simply extends React.ReactElement
const Foo = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren<FooProps>) => {
  return <>children</>;
};

// With generic FC
// Compiler doesn't complain because of JSX.Element can be valid-
// return type because it simply extends the interface React.ReactElement 
const Foo: FC<FooProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return <>children</>;
};
```

**Edit** - This may not be a direct answer, but I hope this example can explain more on why `React.ReactNode` should not be allowed.

`React.ReactNode` is broad, and you can assign almost anything to it. For example

```js
const Foo = () => { return 45; };

// no compile time error because even a functions are a valid ReactNode
const Bar: React.ReactNode = Foo
```

But what happens when we try to render it inside any valid component

**At compile time** -  No error

```js
const FooBar: React.FC<FooProps> = () => {
  // again no compile time error because Bar is a valid ReactNode
  return <div>{Bar}</div>
}
```

**At runtime** - Error Functions are not valid react child

Comment: This is correct but the poster already knows that incompatible type is the cause for error. The question being asked is: why doesn't the rule allow `React.FC` to return the looser type of `ReactNode` rather than `ReactElement`

Comment: I think i have provided a valid reason for why the types are incompatible. Please read the complete answer and try the examples. If you still can not understand, have a look at this basic example in [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCGBjYA5A9gE2gXlg5AogDYQC2EAdsFAD5QDOwATgJYUDmtUFArkUVx4UsAMzYQMAKEltgEJiKTQ4SYMTKVqAb0lQ93eOQBcDZm3YBuSQF9pJahUwQTK5OixRcAIgAWEfmhekvZQ-hpULvhqJORUnlBaBsZQXgBWaD7CaBBetpIA9PlQiGikYCwkTKFMTGhMkiJCyCxoFFAiaGgAFPAmjKwcAJSRquqx2rr6TBDAPExtXh2BNtIFRQDuPhXQwFv0UCz7AG7wRCxSjRTNrVAARvBMXcN4qu7QOvpQ07PzoTGaNiAA)

Comment: @subashManapatra This is not about explaining the rule, which you helped explain clearly. The question here is about the rationale behind the rule that requires `React.FC` to return `ReactElement`, but not `ReactNode`. Why `React.Component`'s `render()` can, while functions can't? Why the guys that make the rule decide that way?

Comment: I don't think "why `React.Component`'s `render()` can return a `ReactNode` and why for `FC`  it has to be `ReactElement`?" is directly related to the question, but it is still a valid and reasonable question to ask. While 'render' in class component  and functional component  can have the same return type, see [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12155#issuecomment-363089187) the type inconsistency is still kept due to the need for backwards-compatibility.

Comment: The first part of the answer only explain about the type incompatibility, which I already know, but the edit part explains better why `React.FC` can't return `ReactNode`

Comment: I included the type incompatibility part of the answer at first because it is somewhat connected to why `ReactNode` type is too broad. Like the example in the `edit` section, there are numerous examples where someone can think the program is safe at runtime, but in reality, there could be numerous bugs because of the type `ReactNode`. Have a look at the [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21699) and [this one](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/35622).

Comment: I agree that the answer doesn't really explain the rationale behind the decision of the React creators to allow children being rendered within the jsx structure (like a fragment) but not returned in a Functional Component, which also becomes part of the jsx structure anyway. Wrapping it in a fragment feels like an unnecessary hacky solution.

Comment: @m3h0w This issue in fact has nothing to do with **React**, it is a result of just **TS** incompatibility. Because of the annotation `React.FC`,  it causes `children` to take an implicit type of `React.ReactNode` which is too broad (will almost accept anything). Please try out the example I provided in the **edit** section of the answer. Also to note CRA has dropped `React.FC` see the [pull request](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177) from its typescript template.

Comment: Great answer, very helpful!
For others, I found [this](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-useless-fragment.md#allowexpressions) ESLint rule config very useful when adding the `<>{children}</>` workaround.